# update NULL values of left joint table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, query-optimization

I have these two tables in my database document and location.

```
select * from  Document     

id  locid   loccode
1   1010    30
2   2020    30
3   3030    30
4   4040    40

select * from location

locid   loccode date    Status
1010    30  20-10-2019  A
2020    30  20-10-2019  A
3030    40  20-10-2019  A
4040    40  20-10-2019  A
6060    30  20-10-2019  A
7070    40  20-10-2019  A
8080    30  20-10-2019  D
9090    40  20-10-2019  D
```

i want to update status in location table whose record (left join null values) not  available Document.
i try below query but it taking more time .

```
update location 
set status='D' 
from location A 
left join document B on A.locid=B.locid and A.loccode=B.loccode  
where b.id is NULL;
```

Please help me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
update location 
set status = 'D' 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from document d
    where d.locid = location.locid and d.loccode = location.loccode
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `document(locid, loccode)`, so the subquery executes fast. An index on `location(locid, loccode)`  might also help.